# How Do You Make A Recursive Boolean Method Of "isSubstring(str1, str2)"

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

```
if (isSubstring(str1, str2))
System.out.println(str1 + " is a substring of " + str2 + ".")
```

and here is the method for isSubstring:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target)
    {   
        if (str == target)
            return true;

        return (isSubstring(str, target.substring(0,5)));            
    }
```

That is what I have in code right now and I can't fathom how you would go about solving this. My instructor is requiring us to use recursion so the return MUST call itself. Normally this problem could EASILY be done with only one line of code:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target)
{
return str.contains(target)
}
```

But I must pointlessly use recursion to solve this and it is EXTREMELY frustrating knowing how trivial this method is and how overly complicated my instructor is forcing us to do this. I don't really know where to start because "return str.contains(target)" doesn't give me a good foundation for how I could try solving this.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

First, you have the right idea, but you want to make the 'next' string you search one size smaller than your current string. So if you were looking in the string Hamburger, you'd search amburger second, then mburger. So when you recur, you might try something like `return isSubstring(str,target.substring(1))` Right now you appear to be using the number 5 as to take the first 5 characters. That's strange because the first time you do it, (Hamburger to Hambu) you won't ever be able to do it again. And if your original target was "ham" then you'd  bomb immediately! Not so good.

Second, it's not enough to test if it's equal. Using the hamburger example, if you were looking for urge, you'd find urger and then go right to rger. You wouldn't ever get urge. So instead of testing for equals, test with `beginsWith()` instead. (If you were shrinking it from the back, like Hamburger to Hamburge to Hamburg, then you'd use `endsWith()`.)

Lastly, you don't have a good path for what to do if you don't reach the goal. If you have `xyzzy` for a target, and you're searching for `bob`, you won't find it. So you need a "base case", which I recommend using as the first line. Something that says "if it would be impossible for the token to be in the target, then let's return false right away".

It's hard and its frustrating, and it seems pointless. But keep in mind he's not trying to teach you to search strings. That's silly, you know how to search strings! He's trying to teach you recursion, which is not easy to "get".

Answer (score 0):

One fix is: Use `equals()` instead of `==` while comparing String/Objects. `==` compares reference equality. `equals()` compares for content equality.

```
if (str == target)
```

should be

```
if (str.equals(target))
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare strings with the `equals()` method: change

```
if (str == target)
```

to

```
if (str.equals(target))
```

Comment: Hey just FYI your website link is sessionful, so it just points whoever clicks it to their own linkedin profile - you want to use the public profile link.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, Asad's advice was useful. Here is a working method for isSubstring:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String str, String target)
{   
    if (target.length() == 0)
        return false;

    if (str.equals(target))
        return true;

    else     
    return (isSubstring(str, target.substring(0,target.length()-1)));            
}
```

I'm not sure if the second "if" should be an "else if" instead.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the function applied to:

- base case) An empty string, must return false;
- base case) A string starting with the once you are looking for, must return true;
- rec case) Else remove the first character and check the rest of the string.

Here the code in Java:

```
public static boolean isSubstring(final String str1, final String str2) {
    if ((str1 == null) || (str2 == null) || str1.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    } else if (str1.startsWith(str2)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isSubstring(str1.substring(1), str2);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isSubstring("hello this is a simple test", "is a"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
```